# Not able to fully see "Create Credentials" page on Google Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-developers-console

As the title says, I'm not able to fully view the Create Credentials page on Google Console. It is being blocked by the hamburger menu on the left.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db4ws.jpg) how it looks. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What type of app are you trying to create credentials for?  May I suggest you change the screen size on your monitor so you can see the full screen or scroll over.    This does not feel like a programing related issue.   Also learning how to take a screen shot of your screen would be a good idea as well. Rather then using your phone.

Comment: I cant recreate this.  It seams to be an error in your browser window.  Try a different browser or close and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

Move your mouse button screen from the API page or else click on the right side page then  it will show the full page. This is just scrolling issue.

Eg : Below is the image shown the same as your issue.
[image]

I have checked in my console, able to see the full page and also able to create the keys.
If there are any other issues, do post your question clearly.

[image]